# Problem with RxJS CombinedLatest when two events from outer observables come at the same time

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

In my component, I want to fetch a new data when the either the the filter or the pagination changes. Additionally, when the filter changes, I want to reset the pagination.

There comes the problem that when the filter changes, the both the `filter$` and `page$` emit new values at the same time; therefore, `this.getDataService.get` (http) is called twice subsequently.

How do I make sure that there is only one http call when filter is applied?

```
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  tableData$: Observable | undefined;

  filter$ = new BehaviorSubject<Filters | undefined>(undefined);
  page$ = new BehaviorSubject<Page>({ page: 1, perPage: 50 });

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.tableData$ = combineLatest([this.sort$, this.filter$, this.page$]).pipe(
      switchMap(([sort, filter, page]) => {
        return this.getDataService.get(sort.sort, sort.order, filter, page);
      }),
    );
  }

  handlePageUpdated(page: Page): void {
    this.page$.next(page);
  }
  
  handleFilterSelected(filters: Filters): void {
    this.handlePageUpdated({ pagination: { page: 1, perPage: 50 } });
    this.filter$.next(filters);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most easily just add a very short `debounceTime()` before `switchMap()`. If you know that the two values are changed synchronously you can even use `debounceTime(0)` that will just proceed with the `next` notification in another JavaScript frame.

```
this.tableData$ = combineLatest([this.sort$, this.filter$, this.page$]).pipe(
  debounceTime(0),
  switchMap(([sort, filter, page]) => {
    return this.getDataService.get(sort.sort, sort.order, filter, page);
  }),
);
```

Comment: can you please elaborate `JavaScript frame`, do you mean using `debounceTime(0)` will make notification run in the next Javascript Stack/Cycle? *(idk the correct terminology)*

Comment: yes, that's what I meant

Comment: can you share any good resources where I can read how `debounceTime/setTimeout`, etc pushes their inside code to the next Call Stack?

Comment: That's how asynchronous scheduler works https://rxjs.dev/guide/scheduler